# problems at a shared-memory based chat application

Tags: c++, linux, memory, shared-memory, shared

I'm trying to build  an application that has two process that uses Shared memory to exchange messages...
what I'm doing as you will see , is requesting for a shared memory and then putting a struct in it .
the struct consist of a string , Bool flag and an enum values ..
the string should hold the message , the flag should tell whether this message has been seen or not by the other side (cause no one is allowed to add a message if there is a unread message in the memory )
I'm suffering from several problems
1- i cant reach the string at the string....
2- when i replaced the string with an int , i face a problem at the client side when trying to get to the memory
and this is the code ...

Server's side:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;
enum e {Server,Client};

struct chat             // struct that will reside in the memory
{


    bool ifread;        //boolian variable to determin if the message has been raed or not
    e who;
    char message[50];
    int msgl;


};

int main(void)
{
string temp;
int shmid;
//key_t key=ftok(".",'a');
key_t key=433;

if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(chat), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
{
cout<<"shmget"<<endl;
return(1);
}

chat *str ;
str = (chat *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
str->ifread==true;

str->who=Server;
if(pid==0)
{

    while(temp!="bye")
    {
        if(str->ifread==false && str->who==Client)
        {
            //cout<<"Client said : ";

            for(int i=0;i<str->msgl;i++)
            cout<<str->message[i];
    str->ifread==true;

        }

    }

}

else if (pid>0)
{
    while(temp!="bye")
    {
    getline(cin,temp);
    str->msgl=temp.length();
    if(str->ifread)
     {
        str->who=Server;
        for(int i=0;i<str->msgl;i++)
         {
            str->message[i]=temp.at(i);
         }

    str->who=Server;
    str->ifread==false;
      }

    else if (!str->ifread && str->who==Client)
       {
    sleep(1);
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
        }
}

}

shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

}
```

Client's side:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;
enum e {Server,Client};

struct chat             // struct that will reside in the memory
{


    bool ifread;        //boolian variable to determin if the message has been raed or not
    e who;
    char message[50];
    int msgl;


};

int main(void)
{
string temp;
int shmid;
//key_t key=ftok(".",'a');
key_t key=433;

if ((shmid = s`hmget(key, sizeof(chat),  0666)) < 0)
{
cout<<"shmget"<<endl;
return(1);
}

chat *str ;
str = (chat *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

pid_t pid;
pid=fork();


if(pid==0)
{

    while(temp!="bye")
    {
        if(str->ifread==false && str->who==Server)
        {
            //cout<<"Server said : ";

            for(int i=0;i<str->msgl;i++)
            cout<<str->message[i];
    str->ifread==true;

        }

    }

}

else if (pid>0)
{
    while(temp!="bye")
    {
    getline(cin,temp);
    str->msgl=temp.length();
    if(str->ifread)
     {
        str->who=Client;
        for(int i=0;i<str->msgl;i++)
         {
            str->message[i]=temp.at(i);
         }
    str->ifread=false;

      }

    else if (!str->ifread && str->who==Server)
       {
    sleep(1);
    //waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
        }
}

}

shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

}
```

Thanks in advance , and sorry for the bad English .....

edit: 
thanks aix but there is another problem ,i.e the client first couldn't get any data from the shared memory even when i used the int x to exchange numbers between them 
the client first kept giving 0 even that the server has placed another value  , and after a while it started giving me an error when calling shmget();

edit(2): i did some changes ,yet it still not working ....

Edit(3): Problem Solved Thank you all guys , turned out to be bad ordering to the flags 
thanks Again ...

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to stick to POD types for shared memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that under the covers `std::string` uses heap allocation.

This means that

```
struct chat
{
   string  letter;
```

doesn't place the entire string into the struct. It places the string *object*, but not necessarily the *character data* associated with the string.

One way to fix this is by replacing `std::string` with `char[N]`.

In general, extra care should be taken when using shared memory with anything that involves pointers or references.

Also, to avoid complications around construction/destruction, it may be best to make sure that `chat` is a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure).

Comment: i did as you told me , yet it's still not working ...
neither the client nor the server can read from the shared memory array

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using an existing library rather than recreating everything from scratch.

For example: [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) provides a [Message Queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue).

Note that the data in the queue should be either POD or use the [interprocess allocation mechanisms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html). If possible, I would advise *serializing* your structures before writing them down in shared memory. It is simpler to handle backward and forward compatibility this way.

Comment: well, im kinda new to this stuff, im trying to learn so that's  why i do prefer to start things out form zero...

Comment: @HSN: In this case, I would be tempted to advise you to take a peek at Boost' implementation... however I should warn it's not easy to read because it's cluttered with work-arounds for various buggy compilers.